# Showing that two cartesian products are equinumerous

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Math 3345
Section 16 Exercise 9

**Let A, B, C, D be sets such that A is equinumerous to C and B is equinumerous to D. Show that AxB is equinumerous to CxD.**

I believe I have the correct answer for when all A, B, C, D are finite. I think it works but I'm not sure if it's correct for when the sets are infinite.

**My answer:**
*I'm using the '||' symbols to denote "the cardinality of"/"the length of", and 'x' to represent Cartesian product (I apologize, I'm new to formatting on the site)*

A equinumerous to C, therefore |A| = |C|

B equinumerous to D, therefore |B| = |D|

|AxB| = (|A|)(|B|) = (|C|)(|B|) = (|C|)(|D|) = |CxD|

Therefore, since |AxB| = |CxD|, then AxB is equinumerous to CxD.

Comment: Why can you do $|A\times B|=|A||B|$?

Comment: That is, essentially, what you have to prove. That this calculation is valid.

Comment: As @Asaf implies, your argument is essentially circular. You need to get back to fundamentals. By hypothesis you have bijections $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to D$. How can you use $f$ and $g$ to construct a bijection between $A\times B$ and $C\times D$?

Comment: It's just rule we introduced earlier in the semester by using the multiplication rule: for two finite sets A, B the cardinality of A x B = cardinality of A times cardinality of B.

Comment: But you can not argument in the same way in the infinite case. See my answer below.

Comment: @Draggfire654: It can’t be a composition, because then its domain would be $A$ or $B$, depending on the order in which you composed them. You need to use $f$ and $g$ somehow to pair up each $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B$ with a different $\langle c,d\rangle\in C\times D$. How can you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Asa Karagila** said your argument is not right since essentially is what you have to prove (at least in the infinite case)

Try the following:

As $|A|=|C|$ then there exists a bijection $f:A\rightarrow C$. Analogous there exist a bijection $g:B \rightarrow D$.

The function $f\times g :A\times B\rightarrow C\times D$ defined as $(f\times g) (x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$ is a bijection. Prove it.

Finally conclude $|A\times B|=|C\times D|$.

Comment: I suppose I don't really know specifically _how_. I understand _what_ a bijection is, and I know in order to prove a bijection exists you must prove that a function is both injective and surjective. But how to show that in specific cases I do not understand.

Comment: Inyective: $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $y=x$. Then you hace to pick two elements with the same image and conclude that the elements are equal
Surjetive: there exist for each $y$ in the range an element $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$. Then you have to pick one element in the range and find an element in the domain such that it is its image.